# Get values from database with specific time interval

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to fetch values from database with specific intervals in C# and need a single query for that.
This is how my Database looks like

```
Id   SensorId    Value        CreatedOn   
------------------------------------------------      
1       8        33.5      15-11-2012  5:48 PM        
2       5        49.2      15-11-2012  5:48 PM
3       8        33.2      15-11-2012  5:49 PM  
4       5        48.5      15-11-2012  5:49 PM  
5       8        31.8      15-11-2012  5:50 PM 
6       5        42.5      15-11-2012  5:50 PM 
7       8        36.5      15-11-2012  5:51 PM 
8       5        46.5      15-11-2012  5:51 PM 
9       8        39.2      15-11-2012  5:52 PM 
10      5        44.4      15-11-2012  5:52 PM 
11      8        36.5      15-11-2012  5:53 PM 
12      5        46.5      15-11-2012  5:53 PM 
13      8        39.2      15-11-2012  5:54 PM 
14      5        44.4      15-11-2012  5:54 PM 
..      ..       .....     ...................
```

The interval is in minutes. 
So, if the interval is 10 minutes, then we need the values at 5:48,  5:58, 6:08 and so on...

I tried doing it with a while loop but it is taking a lot of time as i shoot multiple queries to the database.

Is there any way of getting the data in a single query?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) along with a modulus to get the matching rows (eg, @interval = 10, @offset = 8):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE datepart(minute, CreatedOn) % @interval = @offset
```

---

**Edit**

Note that the above isn't a *general* solution of selecting by intervals.  It will work across *hours* (and therefore across days) for intervals like 2, 3, 4, 5 ... any minute interval which divides into 60.

If you want to use a strange interval like 7 minutes, then you'd have to define a starting time for the interval and calculate the *total minutes* for each row, inclusive of hours/days.  At that point you'd be best to create an indexed, computed column on the table, based on a user-defined function that calculates the interval in question.

Comment: Please don't forget that if this query is important and the table is large, an index on this expression should be created to avoid a sequential scan.

Comment: @MarceloZabani yes, good point ... might even be worthwhile to add a computed column and index against it

Comment: It should be noted, however, that to make use of an index, either `interval` should be constant and the mod operation be indexed, or the query would have to be changed to contain 6 equality comparisons: `datepart(minute, CreatedOn) = 08 OR datepart(minute, CreatedOn) = 18 OR datepart(minute, CreatedOn) = 28` .. and so on with an index on `datepart(minute, CreatedOn)` alone. This could generate a bit of index activity, but it is still better than a sequential scan.

Comment: But i want values for 3 days with 2 minutes interval. So in that case this thing will not work.

Comment: @MayurDhingra well actually, for the interval *2 minutes*, that would still work, because the mod value will pick the correct values across multiple days.  But I take your general point -- it wouldn't work even across hours if the interval were, say, *7 minutes*.

Comment: @dbaseman yes..it wont work in that way. Please suggest something because i have large amount of data and i cannot filter it through iteration so i want a single query to fetch these values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it, explanation is contained within comments in code:

```
/*We want 10-minute intervals starting 
  from minimum date to next day same time*/
DECLARE @startDateTime DATETIME = (
    SELECT  MIN(CreatedOn)
    FROM    #yourTable
)
DECLARE @endDateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateTime)

DECLARE @startDateTimeTable TABLE (dt DATETIME)
INSERT @startDateTimeTable VALUES (@startDateTime)

/*Create a table that contains relevant datetimes (10-minute 
  intervals from starting date to end date)*/
;WITH a AS (
    SELECT  dt
    FROM    @startDateTimeTable
    UNION   ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, a.dt)
    FROM    a
    JOIN    @startDateTimeTable b ON a.dt <= @endDateTime
)
SELECT  *
INTO    #requiredDateTimes
FROM    a
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 32767)

/*Now join data table to datetime table to 
  filter out only records with datetimes that we want*/
SELECT  *
FROM    #yourTable a
JOIN    #requiredDateTimes b ON
        a.CreatedOn = b.dt
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e475/1/0)**

Comment: This is the right approach.  The other samples that rely on modulus imply that there will always be a value at that specific time.  One must first project the each interval date, then find the closest match - probably the last value on or before that date.  HOWEVER, the OP did ask for a LINQ solution.  Something as complex as this answer would beg for a stored proc.  There is probably a way to express this concept in a single LINQ query.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks Matt, I agree, I haven't read that part about C#. OP actually posted another question similar to this, but emphasized that he needs LINQ answer, so I trans-coded this idea to LINQ and posted it as answer to his other question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in two calls to the database (untested):

```
int interval = 10;
DateTime firstDate = db.Items.Select(x => x.CreatedOn).Min();
var items = db.Items.Where(x => (x.CreatedOn - firstDate).TotalMinutes % interval == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the answers that recommend using modulus (%) are making several assumptions:

1. You will always have a reading on every sensor at the exact minute in question
2. You will never have more than one reading in a minute per sensor.
3. You will never have to deal with intervals smaller than a minute.

These are probably false assumptions, so you need a different approach.  First, make a map of all of the time points you are querying over.  Then take the last reading from each sensor on or before that point.

Here's a full unit test showing how it can be done in pure linq-to-objects.  You may need some minor changes to the query to get it to work in linq-to-sql, but this is the right approach.  I used the exact sample data you provided.

As an aside - I hope you are recording your CreatedOn dates in UTC, or you will have ambiguity of sensor readings during daylight savings time "fall-back" transitions.  You need to record as DateTime in UTC, or using DateTimeOffset.  Either are an appropriate representation of *instantaneous time*.  A DateTime with .Kind of Local or Unspecified is only a valid representation of *calendar time*, which is not appropriate for sensor readings.

```
[TestClass]
public class LinqIntervalQueryTest
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SensorId { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var data = new[]
            {
                new Item { Id = 1, SensorId = 8, Value = 33.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 48, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 2, SensorId = 5, Value = 49.2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 48, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 3, SensorId = 8, Value = 33.2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 49, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 4, SensorId = 5, Value = 48.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 49, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 5, SensorId = 8, Value = 31.8, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 50, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 6, SensorId = 5, Value = 42.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 50, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 7, SensorId = 8, Value = 36.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 51, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 8, SensorId = 5, Value = 46.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 51, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 9, SensorId = 8, Value = 39.2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 52, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 10, SensorId = 5, Value = 44.4, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 52, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 11, SensorId = 8, Value = 36.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 53, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 12, SensorId = 5, Value = 46.5, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 53, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 13, SensorId = 8, Value = 39.2, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 54, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                new Item { Id = 14, SensorId = 5, Value = 44.4, CreatedOn = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15, 17, 54, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
            };

        var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        var startDate = data.First().CreatedOn;
        var endDate = data.Last().CreatedOn;

        var numberOfPoints = (int)((endDate - startDate + interval).Ticks / interval.Ticks);
        var points = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfPoints).Select(x => startDate.AddTicks(interval.Ticks * x));

        var query = from item in data
                    group item by item.SensorId
                    into g
                    from point in points
                    let itemToUse = g.LastOrDefault(x => x.CreatedOn <= point)
                    orderby itemToUse.CreatedOn, g.Key
                    select new
                        {
                            itemToUse.CreatedOn,
                            itemToUse.Value,
                            SensorId = g.Key
                        };

        var results = query.ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(6, results.Count);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[1].CreatedOn, results[0].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[1].Value, results[0].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[1].SensorId, results[0].SensorId);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[0].CreatedOn, results[1].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[0].Value, results[1].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[0].SensorId, results[1].SensorId);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[7].CreatedOn, results[2].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[7].Value, results[2].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[7].SensorId, results[2].SensorId);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[6].CreatedOn, results[3].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[6].Value, results[3].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[6].SensorId, results[3].SensorId);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[13].CreatedOn, results[4].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[13].Value, results[4].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[13].SensorId, results[4].SensorId);

        Assert.AreEqual(data[12].CreatedOn, results[5].CreatedOn);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[12].Value, results[5].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[12].SensorId, results[5].SensorId);
    }
}
```